# How do I create DSN of Azure databricks?

Tags: azure-databricks

I'm trying to connect Azure databricks from another application. I need to create a databricks DSN as per the connection steps mentioned in the application. So I'm trying to create the Databricks DSN mentioning the steps given [here](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html) But I'm getting following error message `[Simba][ThriftExtension] (14) Unexpected response from server during a HTTP connection: Unauthorized/Forbidden error response returned, but no token expired message received.`
Sorry I couldn't share with the parameters that I'm using as it's connecting to client's data. Can you suggest me what could be the possible reason for error?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed odbc  driver from [this](https://www.databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download) page.
Image for reference:

[image]

searched for open data source on start menu and opened it and selected Simba Spark under System DSN.
Image for reference:

[image]

filled the required details from azure Databricks, for that
we need to follow below steps:

Navigate to azure Databricks compute option and select the cluster.

[image]

Click on at cluster configuration advanced options and select JDBC/ODBC option.

[image]

Copy host name, port and http path.

[image]

Go to username at left top of data bricks page and select user settings

[image]

Generate access token

[image]

Copy and save the access token.
By clicking on Simba Spark system DSN
we will get below page

[image]

Enter Data source name, description and Enter Server Hostname of Databricks as Host, enter port of Databricks, select Username and password option enter token as username and enter access token of Databricks as password

[image]

select HTTP and enter HTTP Path of Databricks as HTTP path click OK.

[image]

After above setting I tested the connection I go below error

[image]

I selected SSL Option and enabled SSL

[image]

I tested again the connection is successful.

[image]

In this way I created DSN for Databricks.